# How to convert custom time into minutes in splunk

Tags: datetime, splunk, splunk-query

I have a field where it sends the time in either `1h3m45s` or `3m45s` format

I want to convert that into minutes to plot a graph out of it.

i have tried

```
| eval ProcessingTime=replace(replace(replace(LoadTime,"h",":"), "m",":"),"s","")
| eval ProcessingTime=strptime(ProcessingTime,"%H:%M:%S")
```

But it gives blank field.

EDIT:

```
| eval time="1h34m56s"  | eval ProcessingTime=strftime(strptime(time, "%Hh%Mm%Ss"),"%H:%M:%S")|convert dur2sec(ProcessingTime)|  eval TimeinMin=(ProcessingTime)/60  | table time, ProcessingTime,TimeinMin
```

This gives the time in Min which I am expecting but whe I have time=34m56s it does not return anything

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty close, you can use `convert dur2sec()`

```
| eval ProcessingTime=replace(replace(replace(LoadTime,"h",":"), "m",":"),"s","")
| convert dur2sec(ProcessingTime)
```

If it doesn't work, remove the convert line and send what the value of `ProcessingTIme` is. It should look like `HH:MM:SS` format

Comment: works if the time is coming in hours like `2h55m34s` but if it comes only in min like `55m34s` it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

`rex` to the rescue!  This query handles the optional hour value.

```
| makeresults
| eval time="34m56s" 
| rex field=time "(?:(?<hr>\d+)h)?(?<min>\d+)m(?<sec>\d+)s"
| eval hr=coalesce(hr,0)
| eval ProcessingTime=hr.":".min.":".sec
| convert dur2sec(ProcessingTime) 
| eval TimeinMin=(ProcessingTime)/60 
| table time, ProcessingTime,TimeinMin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert time in MM:SS.SSS(minutes, seconds, and subseconds) to a number in seconds.

```
sourcetype=syslog | convert mstime(_time) AS ms_time | table _time, ms_time
```

- The `mstime()` function converts the `_time` field values from a minutes
  and seconds to just seconds.

The converted time field is renamed `ms_time`.

The table command is used to show the original `_time` value and the converted time.

[image]

The `mstime()` function changes the timestamp to a numerical value. This is useful if you want to use it for more calculations.